# How to self-learn law today, like those lawyers in the past who never went to law school?

Tags: legal-education

One can simply read law textbooks and judgements of legal cases, but what else?

Comment: Self-learn with what goal in mind? The best way is in fact "go to law school," that's why there's law school.

Comment: @cpast If you have an answer to contribute, please post it below. Thanks.

Comment: @cpast:  "go to law school" is NOT the best way if one doesn't have the funds or 4 years to spend.

Answer (score 7):

If you simply want to acquire knowledge in law, reading is the most effective way.

Even law courses (at least where I am from) consists of tons and tons of reading. **Read, read, read.** Usually the items are:

1. Legislation (i.e. the actual law). If you are attending an Intellectual Property class, you will be assigned to read Copyright laws. In a Criminal Law class you will read the laws about prosecution, and legal definitions of various crimes.
2. Textbook / lecture slides. They will provide a laymen explanation of the concepts and terms you come across in the legislation, along with simple examples.
3. Legal cases. These are especially important in a country where Common Law is in practice.

Here is a fact: you cannot learn *every* aspect of law. There is simply too much. That is why there are lawyers who specialize in contract, accident compensation, land dispute, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> In the states of California, Maine, Vermont, Virginia, and Washington,
>   an applicant who has not attended law school may take the bar exam
>   after reading law under a judge or practicing attorney for an extended
>   period of time.
>   In 2013, 60 people became lawyers this way out of 84,000 via law schools.

from Wikipedia®

Comment: As far as I can tell this answer has three downvotes, but nobody has commented on what’s wrong with it.

Comment: It's directly copy-pasted with no additional insight or independent commentary. You may as well have just commented with the link to the actual page, at least then the context and exact source of the statements are available.

Comment: @Nij stack doesn’t like you to link to pages because the content of pages goes away or changes. This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is absolutely not the correct way. You should give a link to as precise the source as possible, **then** quote the text as relevant, **then** explain why it *is* relevant. As it stands you could have written anything at all and put "from Wikipedia" under it - we have no way to check that and you haven't shown why this information even matters.

Comment: @Nij The way I answer questions is just fine. Yet this is the second time in one week that you’ve offered your opinion on answers I’ve provided. And not on the accuracy of the information, but on the format and style of the answer. If you really think that users “have no way to check (my answer)” then the problem is not with how I answer but with how you use the Internet. But you know it’s not true; you know there is a way to check the answer, so you’re just being annoying. Not helpful.